# Imperative + pronoun

Tags: syntax, imperative

English and German have vestiges of an imperative followed by a subject pronoun:

> → Be Thou My Vision *(archaic)*
>
> → Don't you talk back to me! *(colloquial)*
>
> → Bitte rufen Sie ihn. *(polite 2nd person)*
>
> → Fangen wir an. *(cohortative)*

These are consistent, as Draconis and fdb point out, but represent exceptional cases in view of the overall verbal system.

- Which is more common cross-linguistically: for an imperative to include the subject pronoun, or to omit it, as is most often done in the languages I understand?
- What do we know about the exceptional cases, as the above seem to be?
- How can we characterize the verb-subject inversion in these cases?

Comment: It's not uncommon in colloquial English nowadays, at least in the negative: "don't you touch that!"

Comment: In German this is not a vestige. "Sie" is mandatory in this construction.

Comment: Thanks; updated to incorporate those examples. I think the premise of this question is still valid.

Comment: In German it is also required for 1st person plural (which is sort of missing in English).

Comment: The fact that these languages are non-pro-drop is key.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Could you clarify that point, possibly with an answer? I think it would be very interesting, but at first glance the connection between omitting subjects in unmarked clauses and in imperatives isn't obvious, particularly considering the special position of the subject (after the verb/auxiliary), at least in the English examples (as I don't speak German).

Comment: Also, is the claim that most non-pro-drop languages have this construction or that most languages with this construction aren't pro-drop?

Comment: @WavesWashSands I don't think it would be a good answer.  In any case my point about non-pro-drop languages (with pro-drop imperatives) is that a sentence without a subject is marked as being imperative.  That is, it is the lack of subject that marks more than the verb conjugation or the intonation.

Comment: @WavesWashSands The other dimension here is order.  Both of these languages have relatively fixed order generally and for imperatives.  Whereas in for example Russian there are imperatives like "Back to me not talk!".

Comment: Now coming back to what is common cross-linguistically, as I always say total counts or averages make no sense because it is not clear if we should count Luxembourgish as much as we count Bengali.  But what we maybe can say is that for example "across families, most inflected languages allow imperatives VO (unmarked) and also SVO, VSO and VOS."

Comment: Overall I do not think it makes sense to view German and English as representing one paradigm, there are fundamental differences between the two.  For example, English 2nd person imperative verb form is indistinguishable from 2nd person indicative.

Comment: I cannot think of a language where the subject pronoun is always required or the default for imperatives (for 2nd person).  But my view is limited to Europe, West Asia and Central Asia.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer (1) If there's a problem with the premise a good answer can still be made resolving my curiosity! (2) Families would be fine for a typological survey — or whatever level of grouping has consistent intra-set patterning. (3) Indistinguishability through non-zeroes isn't the be-all-and-end-all. But I agree that there are differences in how the imperative + pronoun patterns between these languages; they just happen to be the two I know that do this. (4) The German ones for these particular subjects are required/default, just not across the paradigm. Still piques my curiosity!

Comment: I want to suggest that the sentences you list are not really imperative. They are really some kind of irrealis mood; perhaps hortative. For obvious reasons, the meaning is identical to an imperative sentence. But this means the subject is no more or less mandatory than in a "regular" indicative sentence.

Comment: @Wilson But the 'usual' way of forming hortatives in English is to use 'let', so it seems to me a bit ad hoc to claim that 'Don't you talk back to me!' is a hortative, instead of considering it a usual imperative (which, apart from the 'you', it is largely similar to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German case you cite is separate from the English one. In Germanic languages in general, there never was any third-person imperative. But when German borrowed the T-V distinction from neighboring languages, the second person plural (*Ihr*) took on a polite singular meaning. And later, when this stopped being polite enough, the third person plural (*Sie*) took over that role. But German had no third person imperative, so the subjunctive was used instead. *Bitte rufen Sie ihn* is syntactically a subjunctive, and thus the *Sie* isn't optional (since German isn't pro-drop), unlike in *geh [Du] weg*.

In English, however, and in informal German (using the original second-person pronouns *Du* and *Ihr* instead of *Sie*), the subject pronoun is usually *implicit*. This is by far the most common case cross-linguistically, at least in my experience.

By "implicit" I mean that the pronoun still there, but it doesn't appear on the surface. In a language like Ancient Greek, which marks person on the verb even in the imperative, this implicit pronoun still triggers second-person marking. And in English (and several other languages), the implicit pronoun still triggers reflexives: "go let yourself out", not *"go let you out". This would only be expected if there were an invisible subject pronoun there, C-commanding the reflexive.

(There are, in fact, certain constructions that look like imperatives but *don't* have this implicit subject! My introductory linguistics professor would use "bless you" as his only example of this, but "damn you" and many other expletives fit also. See McCawley's paper under the pseudonym "Quang Phúc Đông" for the details.)

The subject-verb inversion here is particular to Germanic, and doesn't quite match any other construction in the language. For example, English negative imperatives use "do"-support even when the verb is "be": "Don't [you] be late!" This doesn't happen in normal indicative sentences: *"He doesn't be late". So the best I can say for this is, it's a special construction used only for imperatives.

Comment: The German polite/intimate dichotomy is a bit more complicated than how  you describe it. This is perhaps of interest: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/er-anrede-18-jhd.2526030/#post-12724536

Comment: @fdb Oh, definitely; I only intend to give a very brief explanation of how "Sie" took on a second-person meaning. What's relevant is that it was originally third-person and maintains that morphologically.